# mongoose is removing empty object out of embedded documents in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

notice the following code, that shows a schema with 2 arrays, one is configured to be from Type:

```
[
  mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
]
```

and one is configured to be from type:

```
[
 {
   value: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
 }
]
```

Here is the code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var schema  = new mongoose.Schema({
  withSchema:    [{  
    value:mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed}
  ],  
  withoutSchema: [mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed],
} , {minimize: false});
var Tweak = mongoose.model('tweak', schema );
```

I update the document using the same data:

```
var data = { 
  "withSchema"    : [ { "value": { a:"221", b:{} } } ],
  "withoutSchema" : [ { "value": { a:"221", b:{} } } ] 
} 
Tweak.findByIdAndUpdate("545680170960023a185ea77e", data, function(err, doc){
  console.log(doc);
  //{ 
  // "withSchema"    : [ { "value": { a:"221" } } ],
  // "withoutSchema" : [ { "value": { a:"221", b:{} } } ] 
  //} 
});
```

How do I prevent this b:{} removal?

**EDIT**:

It turns out this happens only when there is an embeddedDocument inside an Array.

Comment: What is the mongoose version you are using?

Answer (score 24):

Removal of empty objects from arrays - is cause by the minimize option of schema - which defaults to 'true'. Erken answered this in a comment in the down voted answer above - putting it as a separate answer so people can find it.

Can be overridden to 'false' in the schema - then it will save empty objects in arrays

`var schema = new Schema({ name: String, inventory: {} }, { minimize: false });`

from http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#minimize

Comment: Excellent. this should be the accepted answer. Was searching for this, especially with nested objects very useful.

Answer (score 0):

This approach involves first retrieving the document from Mongo, then issuing an update command (triggered by calling save). Take a look at the following code.

```js
var id = "54619b5ef610b70b14a46e79";
Tweak.findById(id, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(result.withSchema[0].value);
    result.withSchema[0].value = data.withSchema[0].value;
    result.withoutSchema.value = data.withoutSchema.value;
    result.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log('updated');
    });
});
```

After saving the document run the code snippet with appropriate 'id' value.

Answer (score -2):

Objects which evaluate to `null` (as your b does) are skipped by mongoose. As an empty or non existant object evaluates to `null` in all MongoDB drivers and even shell queries, too, it actually does not make a difference wether an empty `b` is saved or not.

For example, if you query if b exists, since `b` is empty, it evaluates to `null`and hence the query would fail for that document, regardless if `b`has an empty value or simply isn't there.

Since you already use the `minimize` option, I assume that the empty result, since it evaluates to null, simply isn't displayed. When checking with the shell, the key should be there with an empty value.

Bottom line: for all practical purposes, it does not make a difference wether b holds an empty value or simply isn't there.

Comment: They allow {minimize: false} option for because it makes a difference in many cases... This is a horrible answer (IMO)

Comment: Important to mention that this is an issue of mongoose, if you save empty {} directly threw mongodb-native-driver it will keep the empty objects.

Comment: I fail to see use cases where it makes a practical difference in sensibly created queries. The mere existence of a key should not hold implicit meaning. And when checking `a.b` for null, it really makes no difference wether b is null because it simply isn't there and therefor is evaluated to null or it holds a null value explicitly.

Comment: Let's say you serialize a dictionary into a a json, and the key A holds another empty dictionary and not null. it is data it is not for queries

Comment: An empty dictionary is either empty, which would be null, or would hold keys for null values, which would make the keys of that dictionary evaluate to? Exactly, null. And would that make a difference if `a.b.c` evaluates to null if either b or c evaluate to null? I don't think so.

Comment: What? In programming languages `HashSet empty = new HashSet(); empty != null`

Comment: Right. But if the HashSet is empty, and you try to access a non existing key, the _whole expression_ evaluates to null. But aside that - as I said, the mere existence of a key should not hold and semantic value.

Comment: In the bottom line, you didn't answer my question

Comment: If you read closely, I did. But never mind – you seem to know better.

Comment: @ekeren He did answer your question in the very first sentence. +1